# Use one ListFragment multiple times for multiple data

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

this might be a dummy question, but I am struggling trying to come up with a solution.

In my app I commonly use a `ListView` with a Header, and two `TextViews` for row. But right now for each `ListView` that shows different data I am creating a `ListFragment`. My idea is to keep only one class extending `ListFragment` and use that to show all `ListViews` in the app with the same structure (Header, and two `TextView` for row).

For example:

[image]

In this image I am using two separate `Fragments`. What Would be the best way to re-use the `ListFragment`

Comment: A ListFragment to show a ListView? I don't understand. A ListFragment encapsulates already a ListView as far as i know. How would you place your 'old' ListView in it? Or do you want to use the list fragment as replacement for a listview?

Comment: I want to reuse the ListView encapsulated in the ListFragment in other places of the app.

Comment: That is no answer to my question. Please reread.

Comment: Set header and list values dynamically by passing bundle to a fragment.

Comment: @greenapps, Let's see if I can explain it right. What I am trying to have is a `ListFragment` That I can re-use in others places where I have to show a `ListFragmen`. For example, my 'ListFragment' is called `TwoItemsGenericList`, I want to use it something like this `TwoItemsGenericList(data to show in one place of the app)` as many times as I need. If later I need to show a List with the same characteristics, I would use `TwoItemsGenericList(other data to show in one place of the app)`. I do not know if I am misunderstanding the concept of `fragments`

Comment: Yes you can use a (list)fragment as often as you want.